# Сombinatorial proof for recurrent formula of stirling's numbers

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

What would be combinatorial proof for this formula:

$$S(n,k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}S(n-i, k-1)k^{i-1}$$

where $n \geq k$

Comment: generating functions look like a very reasonable approach, did you try it?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes they do but what I am looking for is combinatorial proof

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: first, prove this by induction, using the basic Stirling number recurrence. Then, think about the combinatorial proof of that recurrence relation, and how it translates to the induction proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For each partition $\pi=\{P_1,\ldots,P_k\}$ of $[n]$ into $k$ parts let $i_\pi$ be minimal such that $P_j\cap[n-i_\pi]=\varnothing$ for some $i\in[k]$. For a fixed $i$, how many partitions $\pi$ are there such that $i_\pi=i$?

Comment: Thanks! But it seems like I already solved this one, I basically did a double counting

Comment: I just noticed this: let us take $n-i$ objects from set then we can partition them in $k-1$ subset, okay we are left with $i$ elements which can be distributed in any set after we fill $k$-th (since before that we filled only $k-1$), so $S(n-i,k-1)$ stands for number of partitioning $n-i$ elements in $k-1$ none-empty sets and $k^{i-1}$ stands for number of ways we can partition elements which are left after we already created $k$ none-empty subsets

Comment: @math-traveler: That’s essentially what I was hinting at: $n-i_\pi$ is the first member of $[n]$ to require a $k$-th part, after which the $i_\pi-1$ larger members of $[n]$ could be in any of the $k$ parts.

Comment: Thank you for awesome hint anyways!

Comment: @math-traveler: You’re welcome!